# Login is not working in production(serve) Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

In XAMPP it works pretty cool but on server I have the message

> These credentials do not match our records

I create my users table with `artisan migrate` and my views are from the login, register an logout for default of the app.

My AuthController:

```
<?php
namespace listas\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use listas\User;
use Validator;
use acTbistas\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;
    protected $redirectTo = '/tablas/title';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }

    //para desabilitar register
    public function showRegistrationForm(){
        return redirect('login');
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you have the record already in production database?

Comment: I mean do you already add the user you are trying to authenticate in your `users` table in the production database?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I am trying to login with the email that I have my table Users. So weird, in Xampp it works, but in production it doesn't work, although that I changed '.env' :( thank you very mas